# Script throwing run time error 13 when multiple cells changed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script to add comments when a time is entered in certain rows in the spreadsheet.  I get a

> run time error 13

when multiple cells are changed.  I used the results of another search attempting to resolve the problem, but it did not work for me.

I am quite new to working with VBA in Excel and appreciate a little patience.  I would also like constructive criticism on improving the script.  Also, on a side note, what are the advantages/disadvantages of doing conditional formatting in the script as opposed to using the conditional formatting tool on the home tab.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim comment As String
Dim time As String
Dim StartCell As String
Dim EndCell As String
StartCell = "A" & Target.Row
EndCell = "R" & Target.Row
time = Target.Value
time = Format(Target.Value, "h:mm AM/PM")
comment = Range("R" & Target.Row).Value

If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
   Exit Sub
End If

If Target.Value <> "" Then

    Select Case Target.Column

        Case 1
            Range("Q" & Target.Row) = "Pending"
        Case 8
            If comment = "" Then
                 Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Tech on site, initial prep, SW and SO# verified"
            Else
                Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Tech on site, initial prep, SW and SO# verified" & Chr(10) & comment
            End If
            Range("Q" & Target.Row) = "In Progress"
        Case 9
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Installing HW" & Chr(10) & comment
        Case 10
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Phase 1 SW Installation" & Chr(10) & comment
        Case 11
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Running TPM and checking devices" & Chr(10) & comment
        Case 12
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Phase 2 SW Installation" & Chr(10) & comment
        Case 13
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Post Imaging Tasks" & Chr(10) & comment
        Case 14
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Upgrade Complete" & Chr(10) & comment
            Range("Q" & Target.Row) = "Complete"
        Case 17
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case ""
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                Case "Pending"
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                Case "En Route"
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                Case "In Progress"
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                Case "Complete"
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.Color = RGB(84, 130, 53)
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                Case "Cancelled"
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Case "Rescheduled"
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Case "Carryover"
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 255)
                    Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 3

              End Select

    End Select

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Conditional formatting done via the `Worksheet_Change` event will not be copied if you copy the cells to another sheet, unlike using the "Conditional Formatting" tool or adding a `FormatCondition`.  There are also certain types of Formatting conditions that are easier/harder/impossible to do in each method too.

Answer (score 3):

Move:

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
   Exit Sub
End If
```

upwards to just beneath the `Dims`

*(there may be other problems)*

## multiple cell change events

Say we are recording status in **A1** through **A10**.  If we enter "complete" in these cells and the adjacent cell is empty, then record the current date in that adjacent cell.  Here is a typical way to handle the entry multiple "complete"s at once:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, Intersection As Range, SingleCell As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(Target, rng)
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each SingleCell In Intersection
            With SingleCell
                If .Value = "complete" And .Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
                End If
            End With
        Next SingleCell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is precisely the issue:  The `.Value` property is Write-Only for a Range with more than 1 cell, even if they are merged, so `time = Target.Value` will throw a Type-Mismatch error (Error 13).  You *can* use `Target.Cells(1,1)` to just look at the top-left cell though, or loop through `For Each OneCell In Target.Cells`

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the additional information!